# Install installation requirements RPM spec

Tags: rpm, yum, rpm-spec

Let's say I have a spec file that looks something like this:

```
Name: mypackage
Version: 1.0.0
BuildRequires: cmake
%if 0%{?rhel} >= 7 || 0%{?fedora} >=17
Requires: python3
%else
Requires: python
%endif
```

I'm aware of `yum-builddep` for install my build dependencies based on the spec, I would really like a `yum-installdep`. Is anyone aware of a simple way to accomplish what I want given that there is some logic in the spec file?

EDIT:

I'm also aware that I can build the RPM, then install it, then uninstall it, but I'm doing this in the context of a continuous testing environment, so I'd really like to just install the dependencies to save the build time of the RPM itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, no. `rpmbuild` builds a spec and when you have a `Requires`, it only checks it during runtime and not during the build. Only `BuildRequires` get checked during build time. You can build an rpm in a single mock environment for one or more `runtime` environments, just as your `spec` suggests.

If you want to test your built `.rpm` for `python` and/or `python3` in a continuous test environment, then you can simply run the `rpm` installation in a `test` mode and check the result. You have to use `rpm` as `yum` doesn't provide a `dry-run` mode.

```
$ rpm -Uvh --test mypackage.rpm
```

or

```
$ rpm -qp --requires mypackage.rpm
```

Above would tell you what packages `mypackage.rpm` would need in a given environment. Based on your `spec` file, if you run the above command in a `Fedora 17+/RHEL7` mock test environment, it would tell you that it requires `python3`, else `python2`

```
$ rpm -q --requires python3-setuptools | grep python
/usr/bin/python3
python(abi) = 3.6

$ rpm -q --requires python2-setuptools | grep python
/usr/bin/python2
python(abi) = 2.7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While it's not exactly what I was hoping for, at least someone who knows more than me also believes its impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

The install-dependencies will get installed automatically when you install the produced package. `yum` (or `zypper`) will manage that automatically for you.

Comment: Right, but I don't want to install the RPM. I'm trying to test the code that the RPM builds, but in order to test it, I need the runtime dependencies. I could always, build the RPM, then install it, then uninstall it, but I really just want the dependencies of the RPM without building or installing the RPM. Does that make sense?